# TypeError occurring while using Celery 2.6.0rc5

Tags: python, redis, celery, celery-task

I am using [Celery 2.6.0rc5](https://github.com/celery/celery), and getting the following error:

```
[2012-06-22 23:01:42,016: ERROR/MainProcess] Unrecoverable error: TypeError('handle_event() takes exactly 3 arguments (1 given)',)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/bmh/celery/celery/worker/__init__.py", line 350, in start
    component.start()
  File "/home/bmh/celery/celery/worker/consumer.py", line 369, in start
    self.consume_messages()
  File "/home/bmh/celery/celery/worker/consumer.py", line 435, in consume_messages
    readers[fileno](fileno, event)
  File "/home/bmh/kombu/kombu/transport/redis.py", line 636, in handle_event
    self._callbacks[queue](message)
  File "/home/bmh/kombu/kombu/transport/virtual/__init__.py", line 461, in _callback
    return callback(message)
  File "/home/bmh/kombu/kombu/messaging.py", line 482, in _receive_callback
    self.receive(decoded, message)
  File "/home/bmh/kombu/kombu/messaging.py", line 454, in receive
    [callback(body, message) for callback in callbacks]
  File "/home/bmh/celery/celery/worker/consumer.py", line 397, in on_task_received
    [callback() for callback in on_task_callbacks]
TypeError: handle_event() takes exactly 3 arguments (1 given)
```

I [pulled both kombu and celery from git just moments ago](https://github.com/celery/celery#using-the-development-version), and am trying this on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS with `redis-server` (2:2.2.12-1build1) installed as the broker.

My config (`celeryconfig.py`) is:

```
BROKER_URL = "redis://localhost:6379/0"
BACKEND_URL = BROKER_URL
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = "redis"
CELERY_REDIS_HOST = "localhost"
CELERY_REDIS_PORT = 6379
CELERY_REDIS_DB = 0
```

My worker (`worker.py`) is:

```
#!/usr/bin/python2.7
from celery import Celery

celery = Celery()

celery.config_from_object('celeryconfig')

@celery.task(ignore_result=True)
def atest(data):
    print "Got data: %s" % data

if __name__ == "__main__":
    celery.start()
```

When I run the worker with `$ ./worker.py worker`, and I call the worker as follows from a python shell:

```
import worker
worker.atest("abc")
```

The worker reports the above error, reports a longer error that ultimately ends with the worker quitting on the following:

```
[2012-06-22 23:01:43,025: WARNING/MainProcess] File "/home/bmh/kombu/kombu/utils/eventio.py", line 95, in unregister
[2012-06-22 23:01:43,025: WARNING/MainProcess] self._epoll.unregister(fd)
[2012-06-22 23:01:43,025: WARNING/MainProcess] ValueError
[2012-06-22 23:01:43,025: WARNING/MainProcess] :
[2012-06-22 23:01:43,026: WARNING/MainProcess] I/O operation on closed epoll fd
```

Incidentally, when I run `$ ./worker.py shell` and run "import kombu; kombu.**version**" it reports 2.2.2, which I understand to be the latest version. It may also be worth noting that [someone else encountered this](https://github.com/celery/celery/issues/808), but seemed to have solved it by updating kombu.

As this is really the simplest celery project I can imagine, I am completely new to celery, and this is a development version, I am a bit stumped on where to go from here and would be grateful for any assistance.

Thank you for reading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I seem to have solved this by updating to the latest version of [Billiard](https://github.com/celery/billiard) with:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/celery/billiard
$ cd billiard 
$ python setup.py develop
```

Comment: Not working :-(... when I do the thrid step it gives me `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 10, in <module>
    from distutils.core import setup, Extension, find_packages  # noqa
ImportError: cannot import name find_packages
` .. what is the problem ?

Comment: @Rania-Boy: Being two years since I solved this, I haven't the foggiest what the problem would be in your situation. I now just use the Debian versions. Perhaps you might want to start a new question that references this one? Just a thought. Cheers.